# Create bar plot using diff() function to determine the change in survival from one event the next

Tags: r, dplyr, visualization

I have a survival dataset `df_survival` with four columns `Date`, `Tank`, `Feed_Group`, and `Census`.

Here is the code to create a the dataset:

```
Date <- c("2020-10-15", "2020-10-15", "2020-10-15", "2020-10-15", "2020-10-15", "2020-10-15","2020-10-15", "2020-10-15","2020-12-05","2020-12-05","2020-12-05","2020-12-05","2020-12-05","2020-12-05","2020-12-05","2020-12-05","2021-01-29","2021-01-29","2021-01-29","2021-01-29","2021-01-29","2021-01-29","2021-01-29","2021-03-13","2021-03-13","2021-03-13","2021-03-13","2021-03-13","2021-03-13","2021-03-13","2021-03-13","2021-04-30","2021-04-30","2021-04-30","2021-04-30","2021-04-30","2021-04-30","2021-04-30","2021-04-30","2021-04-30", "2021-07-06", "2021-07-06", "2021-07-06", "2021-07-06", "2021-07-06", "2021-07-06", "2021-07-06", "2021-07-06")
Tank <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
Feed_Group <- c("Gemma","Gemma","Gemma","Gemma","Mysis","Mysis","Mysis","Mysis","Gemma","Gemma","Gemma","Gemma","Mysis","Mysis","Mysis","Mysis","Gemma","Gemma","Gemma","Gemma","Mysis","Mysis","Mysis","Mysis","Gemma","Gemma","Gemma","Gemma","Mysis","Mysis","Mysis","Mysis","Gemma","Gemma","Gemma","Gemma","Mysis","Mysis","Mysis","Mysis","Gemma","Gemma","Gemma","Gemma","Mysis","Mysis","Mysis","Mysis") 
Census <- c(20,20,20,20,20,20,20,20,15,17,14,10,14,20,16,16,13,16,12,10,14,20,16,16,13,15,11,10,14,20,16,16,13,15,10,9,14,20,15,16,13,14,10,8,14,19,15,15)


df_survival <- data.frame(Date,Tank,Feed_Group,Census)
```

I created this visualization, which shows the average census for each group over time with standard error.

[image]

Now I would like to create a bar graph that shows how many animals died from one event to the next. So from event 1 to event 2, we had a decrease in 6 animals for the Gemma group, from event 2 to event 3, a decrease in  1.25 animals.

I can use the diff() function like below to create a tibble that provides me with a Feed_Group and Census_Dead columns exactly like what I want.

```
df_survival %>%
  group_by(Feed_Group,Date) %>%
  summarise(Census = mean(Census)) %>%
  summarise(Census_Dead = diff(Census))
```

However, I lose the Date column most likely due to the fact that the first point doesn't have a difference of 0, which makes sense. Unfortunately, it's making charting this difficult.

I know I can just create the data.frame and manually place these numbers with corresponding dates since the dataset is so small, but I am curious if it is possible to manipulate the current data to get something like the following:
[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate what values you are trying to get the difference of?

Comment: Sure, There are 6 sampling rounds. Each round we collect Census data on each tank. I want to chart the difference in the census data for every event. So from 2020-10-15 to 2020-12-05, tank 1 lost 5 fish. from 2020-12-05 to 2021-01-29, tank 1 lost  2 more fish.

I would like to plot this difference both from a tank level, but also from a group level. As you can see from the chart above the average loss from 2020-10-15 to 2020-12-05 for the Gemma tanks was 6 fish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr::summarize` can be used to obtain fewer rows for each group (not just aggregate to one row). Alternatively you can use `dplyr::group_modify`.

```r
df_survival |>
  group_by(Date, Feed_Group) |>
  summarize(Census = mean(Census)) |>
  ungroup() |>
  arrange(Date) |>
  group_by(Feed_Group) |>
  summarize(Census_Dead = -diff(Census),
            Date = Date[-1]) |>
  ggplot(aes(y = Census_Dead, x= Date)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = Feed_Group), position = "dodge", stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: ungroup()! That's what I was missing. Thank you!!